# How to add date and time when a form is submitted in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I am making a comment system in php which can store comment ,email and name of the user but I also want to add 2 fields more on my database called *time* - *date* that store the date and the time when user submitted the form automatically! I have searched a lot but I couldn't find any useful article about this. 
If you can know how to do that please help me I would appreciate that!

Here's my code:

```
<form action='comment.php' method='POST'>
    <span>
        <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Your Name'/>
        <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email Address'/>
    </span>
        <textarea name='' name='comment' placeholder='Comment'></textarea>
        <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'></input>
        <p><?php if(isset($errors['name1'])) echo $errors['name1']; ?></p>
        <p><?php if(isset($errors['name2'])) echo $errors['name1']; ?></p>
        <p><?php if(isset($errors['email1'])) echo $errors['name1']; ?></p>
        <p><?php if(isset($errors['email2'])) echo $errors['name1']; ?></p>
        <p><?php if(isset($errors['comment1'])) echo $errors['name1']; ?></p>
        <p><?php if(isset($errors['comment2'])) echo $errors['name1']; ?></p>
</form>
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']));
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']));
    $comment = (isset($_POST['comment']));

    if (empty($name)){
        $errors['name1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:30px;float:right;'>Enter your name</p>";
    }else{
        $name_length = strlen($name);
        if ($name_length > 2 ){
            if (!empty($email)){
                    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $errors['email1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Enter your email</p>"; 
                }else{
                    if (empty($comment)){
                        $errors['comment1'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Write your comment</p>"; 
                    }else{
                        $comment_length = strlen($comment);
                        if ($comment_length < 5){
                            $errors['comment2'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Your comment must be more than 5 words</p>"; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $errors['email2'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:25px;float:right;'>Enter your email</p>"; 
            }
        }else{
            $errors['name2'] = "<p style='color:red;font-family: BCompset, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:30px;float:right;'>Your name must be more than 2 words/p>";
        }
    }

    //check errors
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            $insert_comment = "insert into comments (email,name,comment) values ('$email','$name','$comment')";
            $insert_comment = mysqli_query($con, $insert_comment);
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Put your code in the post, don't just link to it on an external site. If your question is helpful, people need to be able to see your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two fields in your database:

- modified_date date
- modified_time time

Now change your insert query to

```
insert into comments (email,name,comment, modified_date, modified_time) values ('$email','$name','$comment', CURDATE(), CURTIME())
```

Comment: are modified_date date & modified_time time varchar formats in phpmyadmin table or not?

Comment: modified_date should be date type and modified_time should be time type.

Answer (score 1):

Use on of DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP types for your mysql columns.

[Reference for DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html).

Create column timestamp (for example, you could also name it with every name you want), set it on every insert with mysql `NOW()` or with php `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` function:

```
$insert_comment = "INSERT INTO comments (`email`, `name`, `comment`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$email','$name','$comment', NOW())";
```

It will save Datetime, timestamp or date in the format of your choice. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Mysql `datetime` standard format is `Y-m-d H:m:s`. so use `date()` in php like this,

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

You can use `$date` while inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be Creating a single column type `DATETIME`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISITS comments(
    //all your fields
    comment_time DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

and When inserting data in comments table use `now()` function

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments(comment_time) VALUES('now()')";
```

> An alternative method

You can use `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`. Bennefit of using `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME` is you don't have to use `now()` function it will automatically update/insert date & time when any of the column is updated in a row or new data is inserted.

To learn more about `TIMESTAMP` visit [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)